# How to include hidden file with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a file that I have included for a project, when compiled the file is created on the build directory. How to include the file directly in the .exe?

Comment: What kind of file is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at working with [Embedded Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e2c9s1d7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which are files (content, either text or binary) that get embedded into the assembly during compilation:

From MSDN:

> To change a resource from linked to embedded
>
> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
> 2. Click the Resources tab.
> 3. On the Resource Designer toolbar, point to the resource view drop-down, click the arrow, and select the type of resource that you
>      want to edit.
> 4. Select the resource that you want to change.
> 5. In the Properties window, select the Persistence property and change it to Embedded in .resx.

Comment: Ok, for example, I added a .txt file, to call it even I have to change the code?

Comment: If you want to be able to change the text file without compiling it needs to be a **linked resource**.  If you want the file to be part of the assembly to prevent it from going missing you would follow the answer above and make it an **embedded resource**.